# View a website as a Chinese vistor from outside China

Tags: testing

How can you test/develop a website which shows different content to Chinese visitors from outside China? ie. How can I get inside the Great Firewall of China to appear to my website that I'm from China so I can check it's working for Chinese visitors.

Comment: By using a VPN?

Comment: Ideally, but after searching many commercial VPN services, I can't find any that have endpoints inside China. After all most people want to get out not in.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably several ways to do this.

If content is displayed based on *IP location* you would need a VPN.

If content is displayed based on *GEO location* you can spoof you location using several browser extensions or Chrome's Dev Tools --> Sensors.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to setup a VPN on AWS but you need a business license from China to run services in the China region. It's hard to find a VPN provider that has an endpoint inside China.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey I do not use VPNs too often but I did find this article that may be helpful - https://www.techradar.com/news/best-vpn-for-china-our-5-top-choices